# Drop down menu goes wrong after overflow : hidden put

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My dropdown menu currently looks like this :[image]

The Home is not quite at the correct position like how I would like it at the top left, how do I fix this? Many thanks for the help.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  width: 1600px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #333;
}

ul li {
  width: 200px;
  background: #333;
  float: left;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: #0e6ea8;
}

ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: block;
  border: none;
}

ul li ul li {
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}

ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

ul li ul .first {
  position: absolute;
  left: 201px;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul li ul :hover .first {
  display: block;
}

ul li ul .second {
  position: absolute;
  left: 201px;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul li ul :hover .second {
  display: block;
}

ul li ul li ul .seconda {
  position: absolute;
  left: 201px;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul li ul li ul:hover .seconda {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav>
  <div class="nav navbar-fixed-top">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Options<span> &#x25BE</span></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Consumer 
Management&nbsp<span>&#x25B6</span></a>
            <ul class="first">
              <li><a href="#">www.e-homes.com.my</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Project Admin 
Tool&nbsp<span>&#x25B6</span></a>
            <ul class="second">
              <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
              <ul class="seconda">
                <li><a href="#">Download MR</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Download PO</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Download Invoice</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Download lalalala</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I know its just a small thing I missed, would appreciate some guidance on this thank you so much again.

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing ul and li before the second last closing element.

Add d-flex on the ul after navbar-fixed-top element  `<div class="nav navbar-fixed-top">  <ul class="d-flex">`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  width: 1600px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #333;
}

ul li {
  width: 200px;
  background: #333;
  float: left;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: #0e6ea8;
}

ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: block;
  border: none;
}

ul li ul li {
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}

ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

ul li ul .first {
  position: absolute;
  left: 201px;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul li ul :hover .first {
  display: block;
}

ul li ul .second {
  position: absolute;
  left: 201px;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul li ul :hover .second {
  display: block;
}

ul li ul li ul .seconda {
  position: absolute;
  left: 201px;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul li ul li ul:hover .seconda {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav>
  <div class="nav navbar-fixed-top">
    <ul class="d-flex">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Options<span> &#x25BE;</span></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Consumer 
Management&nbsp;<span>&#x25B6;</span></a>
            <ul class="first">
              <li><a href="#">www.e-homes.com.my</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Project Admin 
Tool&nbsp;<span>&#x25B6;</span></a>
            <ul class="second">
              <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
              <ul class="seconda">
                <li><a href="#">Download MR</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Download PO</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Download Invoice</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Download lalalala</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: What does that class actually do? It didn't seem to change the output

Comment: It fixed the issue for me . Which browser are you using ?

Comment: It does work but what I wanted was for the menu bar at the top to be black from the left to the right at the top like in my original pic. It just looks like this now : https://ibb.co/hSSwTU

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML structure is incorrect (closing tags missing) and your CSS contains an error for `ul li`. Corrected below.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  width: 1600px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #333;
}

ul li {
  width: 200px;
  background: #333;
  float: left;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  /* float: none; REMOVED */
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: #0e6ea8;
}

ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: block;
  border: none;
}

ul li ul li {
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}

ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

ul li ul .first {
  position: absolute;
  left: 201px;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul li ul :hover .first {
  display: block;
}

ul li ul .second {
  position: absolute;
  left: 201px;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul li ul :hover .second {
  display: block;
}

ul li ul li ul .seconda {
  position: absolute;
  left: 201px;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul li ul li ul:hover .seconda {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav navbar-fixed-top">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Options<span> &#x25BE</span></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Consumer 
Management&nbsp<span>&#x25B6</span></a>
            <ul class="first">
              <li><a href="#">www.e-homes.com.my</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Project Admin 
Tool&nbsp<span>&#x25B6</span></a>
            <ul class="second">
              <li><a href="#">Download</a>
                <ul class="seconda">
                  <li><a href="#">Download MR</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Download PO</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Download Invoice</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Download lalalala</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Sorry sir nothing changed, the issue still persists